# Question about applying new siding where a picture window is not level

Tags: construction, siding

We're putting new siding on a house where the front picture window is not level ~ it's 1" high on the right side.  For the best visual appearance should the siding be placed level with the earth or level with the window?  Either scenario may create an out-of-level appearance, but which one is the least noticeable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this question really is a matter of opinion but there are some things that can be considered.

1. You could plan the siding installation so as to split the difference so that it is just half noticeable.
2. If the siding is relatively wide respect to the 1" difference in the window out of level amount you could plan the siding runs so that you keep there from being a narrow strip near the bottom of the window. Wider will be much less obvious. If you get lucky with this scheme you would end up also with a wider run above the window as well but if not then aim to optimize at the bottom as that would be more likely to be seen head on.
3. The most invasive would be to check if the window is also not even with the floor inside the house. If it is uneven inside similar to the outside you could then elect to remove and re-position the window make it more even.

Comment: Another consideration is the type of siding... on some, you could set some of it un-level and then cheat your way to level within a few courses; others can't be cheated, so out-of-level at the window would have to be out-of-level for the whole house, which would cause all kinds of headaches. Personally, I'd look seriously at fixing the window.